# JPA OneToMany relations and performace

Tags: jpa, join, relational-database, lazy-evaluation

I have two entities: parent `Customer` and child `Order`.
Each `Customer` has 1,000,000 `Orders` for example, so it is not needed in any given time to load a `Customer` with all `Orders` but I want to have this ability to make join query on these two entities in JPA.
So because of this, I must create `@OneToMany` relationship for making join queries.

My question is: how to get query without making `joinColumn` because even in Lazy mode it is possible to load 1,000,000 objects!
I just want to get query on these object with where restrictions like native join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the `@OneToMany` relationship implicitly set in your `Customer` class than you don't have to. You can execute JPQL queries (in very precise manner) without the marked relationship.

Assume you have:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    // all Customer-related fields WITHOUT @OneToMany relationship with Order
}

@Entity
public class Order {

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer owner;
}
```

Then if you want to get all `Orders` for particular `Customer` you can execute a simple JPQL query like that:

```
// Customer customer = ...
// EntityManager em = ...

String jpql = "SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE o.owner = :customer";

TypedQuery<Order> query = em.createQuery(jpql, Order.class);
query.setParameter("customer", customer);

List<Order> orders = query.getResultList();
```

In this way you can execute the code only when you're really sure you want to fetch `Customer's` orders.

I hope I've understood your problem correctly.

Comment: thnx, nice answer, but I wish there be a restriction annotation on OneToMany for default fetching, what do you think?, because for example I want my Customer entity has top 10 orders that can be accessed via "customer.orders" , but now, if I put OnetoMany it is possible to load all 1000000 records

Comment: So you want an annotation / configuration which would allow you to say how much is 'too much' results to be fetched? I guess such feature would be **highly** vendor specific, as the JPA specification doesn't even require the provider to respect lazy loading. I would go with carefully placed JOINs in your case.

Comment: In the above example, is it possible to run a query for example that retrieves data from the customer table based on conditions based on the order table? For example, can i say give me all customers who have made an order > £50?

Comment: Sure, just add `AND o.value > 50` to the filter section of the JPQL query.

Answer (score 2):

EclipseLink has support for QueryKeys, that allow you to define fields or relationships for querying that are not mapped.   Currently there in no annotation support for query keys, but you can define them using the API and a DescriptorCustomizer.

Also you do not need the OneToMany to query on it, just use the inverse ManyToOne to query,

i.e.

```
Select distinct c from Customer c, Order o where o.customer = c and o.item = :item
```

Or,

```
Select distinct o.customer from Order o join o.customer c where o.customer = c and o.item = :item
```